# Formatting a URL string

Tags: string, formatting, python-3.3

I have a list of cities which have been stripped of punctuation and i need to format the URL correctly.  My lists are ['New', 'York', 'NY'] and ['Lansing', 'MI'] and i need to format the query so that parameter assignments are seperated by the (&) symbol and words in the city are separated by the (+) sign.

For example it should look something like www.url.com/origin=New+York+NY&destination=Lansing+MI

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you attempted to write this code on your own? If so, what do you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

From [the urllib docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

> Convert a mapping object or a sequence of two-element tuples to a “percent-encoded” string

So

```
urllib.parse.urlencode({
  'origin'      : ' '.join(['New', 'York', 'NY']),
  'destination' : ' '.join(['Lansing', 'MI'])
})
```

yields

```
'origin=New+York+NY&destination=Lansing+MI'
```

---

That documentation references the obsolete RFC 2396, but the differences between RFC 3986 and 2396 do not affect query string composition.

Comment: I think `urlencode` moved to `urllib.parse.urlencode` in Python 3.

Comment: @DSM, Yep.  Just updated the doc link to point into the v3 docs from the 2.2.